# Detect application being busy handling keyboard input

Tags: c#, winapi, message-queue

I'm currently writing a program in C# similar to [speed-autoclicker](http://fabi.me/tools/speed-autoclicker) for a particular game where I need to send rapid key strokes. I utilize the WinAPI function [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) to simulate a user pressing `W` while a hotkey is being hold down.

The problem I am experiencing is that the game can't process the input that fast and queues up the windows messages, which results in lag and continued key spamming even after the hotkey has been released. I was searching for a way to find out wether an application is busy processing messages via some "request response" message, like windows seems to do when an application hang ("the application is not *responding*").

Can you help?

Comment: The Windows API call to detect a busy window procedure is [SendMessageTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding [`Thread.Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) between the simulated keystrokes to slow them down to a level the game can handle.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have a  key press/release delay already present and was playing a bit adjusting the value, but it didn't solve the problem. I'll investigate closer and summarize the results when I'm home.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the build configuration from x64 to x86, the lag got less and it works fine now with a 50ms delay. I would accept IInspectable's comment as answer, though.